# Approximating sin(x) using Taylor series until absolute value of a term goes below a certain real value

Tags: c, taylor-series

I want to print the value of sin(x) using its Taylor series.

I must add terms until the absolute value of a term becomes < 10e-06

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
double val(double, double);
int main(void){

    double x,eps=10e-06;

    printf("\nEnter value of x: ");
    scanf("%lf",&x);

    printf("\nCalculated value: %lf\n",val(x, eps));

    return 0;

}

double val(double x, double eps){

    int i;
    double t=x, sum=0;
    if(fabs(x)<= eps) return 0;

    for(i=1;i<=20; i++){

        sum+=t;
        t*=-(x*x)/((2*i+1)*(2*i));
        if(fabs(t)>=eps) break;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

But I am getting the same output as my input(that is I am getting x in output).

Can someone tell me what is wrong.

Comment: Where did you get the formula for the taylor series?

Comment: If x is large, I would guess you're only going through the loop once, and sum == x when you return from `val`.

Comment: @klutt sorry? I used Taylor series

Comment: @Abhay Just didn't look at all like the taylor series at Wikipedia, but it seems to work to there's something I must have missed.

Comment: @klutt Do you mean  x - x^3/3! + x^5/5! - ... ? Well, rewrite it as x - x * x^2 / (2 * 3) + x * x^2 * x^2 / ((2 * 3) * (4 * 5)) - ...

Comment: @Bob__ I'm feeling so stupid now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
if(fabs(t)>=eps) break;
```

You're breaking out of the loop if the term is **greater** than the epsilon value.  You want to check if it's less:

```
if(fabs(t)<eps) break;
```